# how to select the item from resource image array using selector in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, selector, android-recyclerview

this is inside my strings.xml

```
 <string-array name="image_ids">
    <item>@drawable/profie1</item>
    <item>@drawable/settings1</item>
    <item>@drawable/search1</item>
    <item>@drawable/history1</item>
    <item>@drawable/sharing1</item>
    <item>@drawable/alerts1</item>
    <item>@drawable/polls1</item>
    <item>@drawable/news1</item>
    <item>@drawable/support1</item>

</string-array>

    <string-array name="imageactive_ids">
    <item>@drawable/profileactive1</item>
    <item>@drawable/settingsactive1</item>
    <item>@drawable/searchactive1</item>
    <item>@drawable/historyactive1</item>
    <item>@drawable/sharingactive1</item>
    <item>@drawable/alertsactive1</item>
    <item>@drawable/pollsactive1</item>
    <item>@drawable/newsactive1</item>
    <item>@drawable/supportactive1</item>

</string-array>
```

this is my selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@array/image_ids" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@array/image_ids" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@array/image_ids" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@array/image_ids" />
<item android:drawable="@array/imageactive_ids" />

 </selector>
```

i want to use this selector for my recyclerview image items but it gives the error inflating view exception

what should i do please help i am stuck on it for days .

Comment: how can i do it programmatically ?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials for setting up a recycler view.